# outbound link within an iframe not opening

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The iframe is rendered from a html file which contains basic text and some outbound links. The links within the iframe when attempting to open will currently open within the iframe.

Ive tried adding `target="_blank"` or `target="_top"`, but then when you click it nothing happens, this is the same which each `target="..."` that ive seen on stackoverflow or other sites that say might fix the problem. Ive tried others ways through javascript including event listeners on the link which then window.open(url, _blank) ect. Ive tried changing the sandbox settings for `allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox` and researching about sandboxing but this has not fixed the problem.

The iframe first code is:
`<gwd-iframe id="gwd-iframe_1" source="" class="gwd-iframe-op97"></gwd-iframe>`

I have some javascript which uses srcdoc to replace the inner of the iframe so it doesnt need an external .html file to populate it and the html can be held in a variable:

```
function iframeSrc() {
  const iframe = document.getElementById('gwd-iframe_1');
  iframe.srcdoc = iframeInner;
}
```

Code inside iframe: (link is to stackoverflow for this use case)

```
<div style="color: black; font-size: 11px; font-family: Oswald, sans-serif; overflow-x: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 1.4;">
  <p style="margin-top: 0 !important"> <span style="color: #8e5295"><strong>Exercitation incididunt tempor.</strong></span><br> <strong>Dolore minim cupidatat.</strong> <br> </p>
  <p><strong>lorem</strong><br> ipsum<span>&#174;</span> Fugiat occaecat consequat labore anim incididunt irure adipisicing labore dolore veniam consequat occaecat nulla.<br> <span>&#8226;</span> Elit dolor veniam sed culpa quis est do dolore velit minim nulla.<br> <span>&#8226;</span> Anim ut in irure id cupidatat quis cupidatat eiusmod ex irure reprehenderit elit in ad.<sup>2</sup> </p>
  <p><strong>References</strong> Veniam amet. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors after you click the link. Many sites will have the [`X-FRAME-OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header set so that third party sites cannot display them in iframes in order to prevent spoofing/phishing attacks

Comment: When i click the link there are 0 errors in console, which is the most confusing thing. I cant even find anything to really go off and research the fix